# Reload Page in Div

Tags: html, refresh

I have a php script that monitors one of my network devices and shows various basic stats on screen. This works fine and I don't need to change what it reads.

I currently have this script configured so it reloads every 5 seconds to give a near live update.

I'd like to change it so this page is loaded into a DIV and only that DIV is refreshed.
I've got it working successfully with JQuery and using an Ajax DIV refresh script I found online.

The issue I have is the amount of resources this method uses compared to a normal page refresh.

The basic script after load averages around 3% CPU usage.
The JQuery version around 22% and the Ajax around 16%.

Is there any way to reload a page into a DIV that doesn't start using a lot more resources. ?

The jquery I used is :

```
 $("#new_stats").load('stats.php');
   }, 3000);
```

The Ajax script is :

```
var seconds = 5;
var divid = "new_stats";
var url = "stats.php";

////////////////////////////////
//
// Refreshing the DIV
//
////////////////////////////////

function refreshdiv(){

// The XMLHttpRequest object

var xmlHttp;
try{
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e){
alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
return false;
}
}
}

// Timestamp for preventing IE caching the GET request

fetch_unix_timestamp = function()
{
return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))
}

var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
var nocacheurl = url+"?t="+timestamp;

// The code...

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}
}
xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

// Start the refreshing process

window.onload = function startrefresh(){
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}
```

Thanks :)

**UPDATE**
This is the JQUERY I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#new_stats").load("stats.php");

   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#new_stats").load('stats.php');
   }, 5000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Sorry only posted a part of it last time.

Comment: Anyone know another way to do this with out consuming additional resources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an interval:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#new_stats").load("stats.php");

    setInterval(function() {
        $("#new_stats").load('stats.php');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: @MacMan Updated my answer. This code will refresh the 'stats.php' file every 3 seconds. If this isn't working then can you please state what errors you are getting in your console or what errors you are getting in your PHP.

Comment: Thanks this does work. But I'm still seeing higher CPU usage then just refreshing the page.